# Dynamics CRM: Bring Activity Type between organizations to Sync

Tags: dynamics-crm

I have an activity(Activity_ABC) which has different Activity Type code value across QA(1001) and Production(1002) organizations.This leading to Views which use Activity Type in the Filter criteria to break every time deployment is done from QA to Prod,
needing a manual update.

I found one supported way would be to restore one organization, but looking forward for any customization method for it.
What would be the impact if I update the Activity Type Global System option set xml say on QA to make it 1002 for Activity_ABC.

Answer (score 0):

Having out of sync customizations, that too Entity (custom activity) created separately in different order on each instance (of dev/uat/prod regions) is going to be hell.

Try to restore/refresh the Prod instance to lower regions to have all in sync - BEST option.

Editing customizations directly in xml file - **unsupported** - unrecommended option. Which you may get succeed, but start to play around after taking backups.

Verify if that code is assigned to any other entity/activity before doing so.